# Finding $\iint_K y \,dxdy$, with $K$ bounded by the $x$-axis and one arch of the cycloid $x=R(t-\sin t), y=R(1-\cos t)$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I'm not sure how to approach this problem. I tried substituting the variables in the integrand, but I failed at expressing the bounds in terms of $x$ or $y$.

I thought: $0 \le x \le 2R\pi$ and $0 \le y \le \dots$. (I'm not sure about the upper bound of $y$).

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the function
$$\psi:\quad t\mapsto x(t)=R(t-\sin t)\qquad(0\leq t\leq 2\pi)$$
is monotonically increasing there is a function $f$ such that $$y(t)=f\bigl(x(t)\bigr)\qquad(0\leq t\leq 2\pi)\ ,$$
namely $f(x)=y\bigl(\psi^{-1}(x)\bigr)$.
We can therefore assume that one arch $\gamma$ of the cycloid is given by $$\gamma:\qquad y=f(x)\quad (0\leq x\leq 2\pi R)\ .$$ Then
$$J:=\int_K y\>{\rm d}(x,y)=\int_0^{2\pi R}\int_0^{f(x)} y \>dy\>dx={1\over2}\int_0^{2\pi R}f^2(x)\>dx\ .$$
We now substitute
$$x:=R(t-\sin t)\quad(0\leq t\leq 2\pi)\ .$$
Then $dx=R(1-\cos t)\>dt$, and  $f(x)=y=R(1-\cos t)$,
so that
$$J={R^3\over2}\int_0^{2\pi}(1-\cos t)^2(1-\cos t)\>dt=\ldots\quad.$$

Comment: Thank you so much. One more question regarding this solving technique: can I use this method for all curves that are expressed parameterically (f.ex. an astroid, $x=a \cos^3 t, y = a\sin^3 t\,\, (0\le t \le \pi/2)$)?

Comment: @Zachary: See my edit, and draw a figure!

Comment: The function $\psi: t \to x(t) = a \cos^3 t \quad (0 \le t \le \pi/2)$ is monotonous, therefore your method can be applied in this case too.